# Gradle does not retrieve latest version from Artifactory

Tags: gradle, artifactory

I have a problem with Artifactory and gradle.

One project (library) compiled and deployed on Artifatory.
Maven metadata seems to be updated as I expect:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<metadata>
  <groupId>com.mywork</groupId>
  <artifactId>client</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.23</version>
  <versioning>
    <latest>1.0.23</latest>
    <release>1.0.23</release>
    <versions>
      <version>1.0.18</version>
      <version>1.0.19</version>
      <version>1.0.20</version>
      <version>1.0.21</version>
      <version>1.0.22</version>
      <version>1.0.23</version>
    </versions>
    <lastUpdated>20170116084317</lastUpdated>
  </versioning>
</metadata>
```

In gradle that uses this library it's

```
compile(group: 'com.mywork', name: 'client', version: '1.0.+')
```

The problems is when one version is downloaded - the only way to move to next one is run with **--refresh-dependencies**.

In **--debug** logs I can see that my artifact version stored in file named **module-versions.bin** and gradle don't even check maven metadata.

The solution described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34365443/gradle-not-picking-up-latest-library-version-from-artifactory) in not working for me.

Is any way to force check for latest version on every compilation? Without **--refresh-dependencies** and/or removing **module-versions.bin**.

Comment: Just came across this exact problem.  Here we are limited by the technology of our time...

Answer (score 0):

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        cacheDynamicVersionsFor 0, 'seconds'
        cacheChangingModulesFor 0, 'seconds'
    }
}
```

Comment: Not working. Version does not get updated, when I manually delete my artifact from gradle cache - it's download last known version, which is not the latest. May be problem with gradle version? I did not succeeded  to find since what version those vars exist in gradle.

Comment: Where are you putting the config? Same `build.gradle` as you are declaring the dependencies? or `root/build.gradle`?

Comment: Above dependencies block in build.gradle